# R - Loop Need Assistance with writing a loop and storing the results in a data frame in R

Tags: r, dataframe, loops, linear-regression

I have an enormous data set. I want to sample it K times, run a linear regression and extract the RMSE each time to store in a data frame.

pseudo code:
`rmse <- emptyDataFrame{}`

`for (i in 1:100)`

`sample_n(df, n, replace=True)`

`model <- lm(y ~ ., data = df)`

`rmse <- sqrt(mean(y_pred  -  y)^2))`

Can anyone give me the missing details?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add a `[i]` after `rmse` to store the values in different indexes. Also, i don't know how your function `sample_n` works, but perhaps you need to save its output in a new variable to pass it to `lm`.

Also, the formula for RMSE is `sqrt(mean((y_pred  -  y)^2))`.

```
rmse <- c()

for (i in 1:100){
  df_sampled <- sample_n(df, n, replace=True) 
  
  model <- lm(y ~ ., data = df_sampled) 
  
  rmse[i] <- sqrt(mean((y_pred  -  y)^2))
}

as.data.frame(rmse)
```